# Referencing another cell in another sheet depending on its value

Tags: excel

Here is my situation. I have two sheets. They are in a certain format, like this:

```
Sheet 1
Id-Number   Id-Name

Sheet 2
Id-Number   Id-Other Value
```

I would like to take `Id-Other Value` and add it after `Id-Name` in the first sheet.
I was thinking of doing it like this:

```
Id-Number   Id-Name    (Get "Id-Other Value" from Sheet 2 where Id-Number = Id-Number)
```

I realize I could just copy the values over by hand. But I will be in this situation in the future and I want to save myself some time.

Is there a way to do this automatically?

Comment: Use the VLOOKUP() Excel Worksheet function (re: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-function-HP010343011.aspx ). Rgds,

Comment: Thanks Alex! I ended up using VLOOKUP. It's awesome. 
Here's the video guide I found before seeing your comment.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-WAEzokHSJM

Comment: You are welcome. Good luck with your project. Rgds,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `VLOOKUP`. Here is an example:

```
Sheet 1
     A           B          C
1    Id-Number   Id-Name    ID-Other Value   
2    11111       ABC        =VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A2:B4,2,0)  //Apples
3    22222       DEF        =VLOOKUP(A3,Sheet2!A2:B4,2,0)  //Oranges
4    33333       GHI        =VLOOKUP(A4,Sheet2!A2:B4,2,0)  //Bananas


Sheet 2
     A           B
1    Id-Number   Id-Other Value
2    11111       Apples
3    22222       Oranges
4    33333       Bananas
```

Comment: Thanks Alex! Vlookup is great!